# Google Cloud Storage One file multiple access at the same time

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using GoogleCloudStorage in my GAE-Projekt and I would like to know what happens when I access with two instances one file at the same time. I created a PHP-script, that opens a file, read it's content, add some content and save it like this:

```
$userContent = json_decode(file_get_contents("*** link ***"));
$userContent->abc = "test"; // Do some changes
file_put_contents("*** link ***", json_encode($userContent);
```

My worry is that while I open the file, another instance opens it too and data gets lost. So what will happen in this case?

- Is the file locked and the other instance is waiting?
- Is the file locked and the other instance aborts?
- Is the data getting lost?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage, per se, imposes no locking.  Both reads and writes to GCS objects are **atomic** -- each read will get the contents of the object entirely from one version; each write will totally replace the object.  No "intermediate stage" (with part of the object being from one version and the rest from another version) can ever possibly exist.

But of course it **is** quite possible to "lose data" if multiple tasks are attempting to "modify" a GCS object independently and w/o somehow syncing or negotiating among themselves!  That's because GCS has no concept of "modifying" an object: only of **reading** the object, and **replacing** the object entirely.

So, a task trying to "modify" a GCS object actually reads it, modifies whatever it has **in memory**, then overwrites the object with that memory's contents.  If multiple tasks are independently "overwriting" the very same object, the last overwrite will "win", and obliterate previous ones.

I have no idea what a "GAP-Projekt" is, but assuming we're actually talking about GAE (as per tags), it's reasonably easy for multiple instances of a GAE app to sync up among themselves, using shared resources such as memcache or the GAE datastore.  Such resources would be used to denote which instance "currently owns" a GCS object, by convention; the other instance would wait its turn...

Comment: Yes I ment GAE ;-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is not locking - if you're concurrently modifying the data in different ways then it's likely your data will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to rely on GCS [preconditions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_Preconditions)

This allows updating a file only if it wasn't changed after reading. See the docs:

> Preconditions are often used in mutating requests — uploads, deletes, copies, or metadata updates — to prevent race conditions. Race conditions can arise when the same request is sent repeatedly or when independent processes interfere with each other. For example, multiple request retries after a network interruption, or users performing a read-modify-write operation on the same object can create race conditions.